# Logarithm inequality $ \log_{1/2} (A) > 3 $

Tags: logarithms

If $ \log_{1/2} (A) > 3 $ then how can I write it in exponential form?

And how to solve this?

Comment: @samjoe my bad :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$3<\dfrac{\log_2A}{-1}\iff-\log_2A>3\iff\log_2A<-3\iff A<2^{-3}$$

Comment: what if the logarithm's base were $ \frac{3}{2} $ instead of $ \frac{1}{2} $

Comment: @MaanavRoy $(3/2)^x$ would be an increasing function of $x$. So, we would have $A >(3/2)^3$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $(1/2)^x$ is a (montonically) decreasing function of $x$. Thus since $\log_{1/2}(A) > 3$, $(1/2)^{\log_{1/2}(A)} = A < (1/2)^3 = 1/8$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $f(A) = (\frac{1}{2})^A$. Notice that it is strictly decreasing on its entire domain, so if $x < y$ then $f(x) > f(y)$. Thus, since $3 < \log_{1/2}(A)$, we know that:
$$
\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^3 > \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{\log_{1/2}(A)} = A
$$
so that $A < 1/8.$